# Can we compile SQL statements through cruise control

Tags: sql, clearcase, cruisecontrol

Can you please let us know how can we compile SQL procedures through Cruise control.

These procedures will be there in clearcase.

Answer (score 0):

As illustrated in "[Continuous integration with IBM Rational ClearCase Remote Client](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/09/continuousintegrationrationalclearcaseremoteclient/)", you can compile whatever you want with CruiseControl and ClearCase:

[image: cc]

It is only a matter to get from ClearCase the right (or latest) version of the files, and launch the right script (like one compiling SQL procedures) on said files.

Comment: How can we get the sql compiler?

Comment: @user1383839 that I don't know: it seems a separate issue than CruiseControl and CC. It needs to be installed on the agent for your script to call it.